# Analytic functions and antiderivative

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Suppose $g(z)$ is analytic on all of $\mathbb{C}$ except at finitely many points $z_1, ..., z_n$ satisfying $|z_i| < 1$ for all $i$. Show that $g(z)$ has an analytic antiderivative on $|z| > 1$ if and only if $\int_{|z|=1} g(z) dz = 0$.

Comment: The post settles the "if" part. The "only if" holds because the contour integral is $\int_{|z|=1}g(z)dz=\lim_{r\downarrow 1}\int_{|z|=r}f'(z)dz=0$ if there exists an analytic anti-derivative $f$ of $g$ in $|z| > 1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** The sum of the residues of $f$ is $0$. Thus, Cauchy's Theorem says that the integral around any closed loop, whether it circles $\{z:|z|\le1\}$ or not, is $0$. Thus, the integral is well-defined at any point, independent of the path taken.